# Cheerio error handler node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I start a new project using Node.js and I'm wondering if there is any way to manage what returns from cheerio.load() function.
I've tried to use callback and promises(then and catch) but it did't work.

example:

```
 var $ = cheerio.load(html);
 //what if it's falied ???? how I can handle it?
```

I'm asking this because I tried to run script serval time but sometimes it's work and sometimes not.

BTW:
I'm using cheerio module from npm site -> `npm install cheerio.`

thanks :-)

Comment: As long as you pass it a string, it should do SOMETHING. Technically, there's no syntax errors in HTML. (If you do something weird in an HTML file, it's up to your browser to correct it and continue loading the file). Can you provide an example of it 'not working'? What did you pass it? What does it do?

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/cheerio/lib/parse.js:55
    var oldParent = node.parent || node.root,
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null`

Comment: Before `var $ = cheerio.load(html);`, add this line: `console.log(html)`. The error that you just posted usually means you're passing *not a string* to cheerio. That `console.log` will tell you want `html` is right before cheerio loads it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block since you do not know if the cheerio operation will succeed.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

try {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e) // handle error
}

console.log('continue script')
```